# Providing GPS location data to Android Auto

Tags: android

For an automotive project, we have two ECUs. One where Android Auto runs, and the other one gets GPS data (as NMEA sentences). We can send the data over Ethernet.

What are the steps to get the NMEA/GPS data we receive over the Ethernet port into the Android system?